# VSCode - JavaScript - ReferenceError: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript

Relatively new to JS, Working through a tutorial in Visual Studio Code. Within the "let" definition it is reading "fullName" as a string and not a defined variable. Reviewed Git/StackOverflow for an hour and still cannot determine what the issue is. Thank you for your help!

Error - `ReferenceError: fullName is not defined`

```
var name = "Bob";
if (name == "Bob") {
    let fullName = "Bob Smith";

}
console.log(fullName);
```

Appears to be reading the definition as a String

Comment: put var and it will work instead of let

Comment: That worked thank you! Why does it not allow the same definition with the use of "let"?

Comment: `var` is function scoped, while `let` is block scoped. Here is the documentation for the [`let` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Answer (score 1):

This is because fullName is not in scope where it was used.

Learn about variable scoping here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-scope-in-javascript-cbd957022652/

TLDR: Accessing fullName outside the block it was defined in will not work. This will work

```
var name = "Bob";
if (name == "Bob") {
    let fullName = "Bob Smith";
    console.log(fullName); 

}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you for the explanation and link!

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is that `fullName` is block scoped because you have used `let` keyword use `var` instead to access `fullName` outside of block .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var name = "Bob";
if (name == "Bob") {
    var fullName = "Bob Smith";

}
console.log(fullName);
```

var and let are not the same